# What are the drawbacks of foreign key constraints that reference non-primary-key columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design

I want to know if there are any drawbacks between a referential relation that uses primary key columns versus unique key columns (in SQL Server a foreign key constraint can only reference columns in a primary key or unique index).

Are there differences in how queries are parsed, in specific DB systems (e.g. Microsoft SQL Server 2005), based on whether a foreign key references a primary key versus a unique key?

Note that I'm *not* asking about the differences between using columns of different datatypes for referential integrity, joins, etc.

Purely as an example, imagine a DB in which there is a 'lookup table' `dbo.Offices`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Offices (
    ID   int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_Codes PRIMARY KEY,
    Code varchar(50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT UQ_Codes_Code UNIQUE
);
```

There is also a table `dbo.Patients`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Patients (
    ID         int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_Patients PRIMARY KEY,
    OfficeCode varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT FK_Patients_Offices FOREIGN KEY ( OfficeCode )
        REFERENCES dbo.Offices ( Code )
);
```

What are the drawbacks of the table `dbo.Patients` and its constraint `FK_Patients_Offices` as in the T-SQL code above, versus the following alternate version:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Patients (
    ID       int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_Patients PRIMARY KEY,
    OfficeID int NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT FK_Patients_Offices FOREIGN KEY ( OfficeID )
        REFERENCES dbo.Offices ( ID )
);
```

Obviously, for the second version of `dbo.Patients`, the values in the column `OfficeID` don't need to be updated if changes are made to values in the `Code` column of `dbo.Offices`.

Also (obvious) is that using the `Code` column of `dbo.Offices` for foreign key references largely defeats the purpose of the surrogate key column `ID` – this is purely an artifact of the example. [Is there a better example of a table for which foreign key references might *reasonably* use a non-primary key?]

Comment: I'm starting to think that the uniqueness of a primary key probably implies that the differences, e.g. in performance, between a foreign key that references a primary key versus one that references a unique key are minimal.

Comment: If the office codes are subject to change, you'd be well advised to whack `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on the foreign key constraint.

Comment: @Damine_The_Unbeliever – that is good advice, but it's not related to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no drawback.

However..

Why do you have an ID column in the Offices table? A surrogate key is used to reduce space and improve performance over, say, a varchar column when used in *other* tables as a foreign key.

If you are going to use the varchar column for foreign keys, then you don't need a surrogate key.

Most benefits of having the IDENTITY are squandered by using the Code column for FKs.

Comment: "Most benefits of having the IDENTITY are squandered by using the Code column for FKs." But the main drawback of *having* the IDENTITY, namely *requiring* another join to get readable output, is neatly sidestepped by using another candidate key. Save one join here, one join there, and pretty soon queries that used to need nine joins now only need two. That *can* amount to a big performance gain. (But probably not in the OP's case.)

Comment: @catcall, that gain is offset by the performance loss of having to update FK key fields as the PK changes and the continual rearrangement of records in the clustered index and the performance loss of joining on a varchar vice an int.

Comment: @HLGM: You might be surprised. We tested our in-house system with natural keys. PKs don't change often. 80% of the queries were faster than with ID numbers, mainly because there were fewer joins. In a couple of cases, queries using id numbers and lots of joins took 30 times as long to return.

Comment: I can see now that I might be better served by adding a 'symmetric' example to clarify that I'm not asking about the relative merits of using a key composed of a `varchar` column versus one composed of an `int` column, nor am I interested in the religious wars concerning the use of surrogate or natural keys. I'm purely interested in the differences between the use of a primary key versus a unique key as the reference for a foreign key constraint.

Comment: You're entirely right about the redundancy of the `dbo.Offices` table including the `ID` column if the `Code` column is used for foreign key references.

Comment: Where is the proof of the statement "There is no drawback".  Tom Kyte would include a SQL script with plan output showing differences or not.  I'm surprised that this was accepted as an answer at face value.  Not meaning to be inflamatory but just reminding that answers regarding performance usually have a reference to documentation or performance example.

Comment: You could generate a plan showing good or bad, but differences would come from poor or non-covering indexes on the super/alternate key used in the FK.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think there would be any drawbacks??

Quite the contrary! It's good to see you're enforcing referential integrity as everyone should! No drawbacks - just good practice to do this!

I don't see any functional difference or any problems/issues with referencing a unique index vs. referencing a primary key.

---

*Update: since you're not interested in performance- or datatype-related issues, this last paragraph probably doesn't add any additional value.*

The only minor thing I see is that your `OfficeCode` is both a `VARCHAR` and thus you might run into issues with collation and/or casing (upper-/lower-case, depending on your collation), and JOIN's on a fairly large (up to 50 bytes) and varying length field are probably not quite as efficient as JOIN conditions based on a small, fixed-length `INT` column.

Comment: Our database is case-insensitive while our application is case-sensitive, so I can attest to the issues you raise by using VARCHARs.  Ran into an issue like this just last week.

Comment: I added to my question to hopefully clarify what I'm asking.
I wasn't asking about the drawbacks of referential integrity itself (of which there are at least performance costs [and benefits]).
Nor was I asking about the differences between using an `int` column versus a `varchar` for the key columns.

Comment: @Zerofiz: In most businesses, the database predates the applications. An application that makes unwarranted assumptions about how its database works has application design problems, not database design problems.

Answer (score 1):

A primary key is a candidate key and is not fundamentally different from any other candidate key. It is a widely observed convention that one candidate key per table is designated as a "primary" one and that this is the key used for all foreign key references.

A possible advantage of singling out one key in this way is that you make the use of the key clearer to users of the database: they know which key is the one being referenced without looking in every referencing table. This is entirely optional however. If you find it convenient to do otherwise or if requirements dictate that some other key should be referenced by a foreign key then I suggest you do that.

Comment: I reread your answer and you've definitely identified one significant drawback of using a non-primary key as a foreign key reference – it's unexpected. For one of the apps that I work with, this has been a major annoyance – many tables are referenced by their 'code' column (almost certainly for better data readability when writing ad-hoc queries) instead of the 'auto-ID' primary key column.

Answer (score 0):

The most significant one I can think of is that, if they ever renumber the offices, you'll either lose integrity or need to update both tables. However likely that might be.

The performance consequences are vanishingly small unless you have irrationally large office codes, and even then less than you probably expect.

It's not considered a significant determinant of database design for most people.

Comment: ???? If the `ID` of an office changes, then the reference on `OfficeCode` is still totally and utterly valid..... or what do you mean? When someone changes the `OfficeCode` ? One could add a `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause to the FK relationship to manage that...

Comment: If your office number ("w-823", ID=562) changes from "W-B23" to "W-B23a" because they split it into two (W-823a and W-823b), for instance, then the office table can change without requiring your patient record to change.

Comment: OK, good point - plus as I mentioned, JOINs on a smaller ID like INT would be better for performance, too, most likely.

Comment: Regardless of whether the foreign key uses the primary key or the unique key, changes to the reference columns will either break referential integrity or require an update.

Comment: Is it really true though that the differences between `int` and `varchar(x)` [where `x` is 'significant'] key columns are not considered a significant determinant of database design for most people? I'm not sure that's a free non-decision (based on my own experience)!

Comment: @Kenny Evitt, but a PK that is a surrogate key is far less likely to change than a string-based field. That's why it is usually better to use a surrogate key if you have one for enforcing the referential integrity.

Comment: @HLGEM – you're right; that's a performance issue I've encountered in apps I've worked with, hence my question about the data type not being a "significant determinant of database design for most people". If that's not a significant design decision for most people, it should be.

Comment: @Kenny Evitt: INT is 4 bytes - VARCHAR(4) takes the same amount of space.  VARCHAR(5+) takes more bytes as the number of characters increases - this is where the performance concern lies.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you add an index on the code column (which you definitely should as soon as you reference to it), is there anything to be said against getting rid of the entire ID column and using the code column as PK as well?

Comment: For the reasons I just mentioned (large key, varying length key), just using `OfficeCode` as your **primary** (and thus automatically by default **clustering** key) would be a really bad idea! Don't do that !!

Comment: A **good** clustering key should be NUSE - *n*arrow, *u*nique, *s*tatic and *e*ver-increasing. See [Kim Tripp's excellent blog post](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx) on that topic

Comment: Ok, thank you for that insight.

What from my point of few is a major drawback in the "Code as FK" approach is that is might harm maintainability, since new developers writing views, joins, ... they might expect the ID column to be the FK. Whatever you do, you should be consistent in that regard in your DB design.

Comment: In SQL Server (and I imagine, any SQL DB), there is automatically an index on the `Code` column of the table `dbo.Offices` because of the unique key constraint on that column.
I added to my question to clarify that I wasn't asking about the design of the table `dbo.Offices`. I want to know about any differences between a foreign key that references a primary key versus one that references a unique key.
You're right about consistency (where it's cheap to achieve, e.g. new apps).

Answer (score -1):

Big flaw
We were able to enter some value into **dbo.Patients.OfficeID** that is not there in **dbo.Offices.ID**
There is no meaning to say that there is a reference.

Comment: How were you able to enter this value?

Comment: You have made a unsubstantiated claim that's potentially interesting, but your subsequent statement is false regardless of the veracity of your claim.